How do I open two instances/tabs/windows of Chrome with the same url from the command line so that the page is displayed in different languages
I have a web page that detects language, and I have been tampering with the command line arguments for Chrome to get two windows with the same page, but I can't get the second call do what I want:
start chrome https://mypage --accept-lang=sv --lang=sv --process-per-tab --override-language-detection --reduce-accept-language 
start chrome https://mypage --accept-lang=da --lang=da --process-per-tab --override-language-detection --reduce-accept-language

I have tried with --incognito and also chrome /new-window.
The first command does what I want it to do, but the second just keeps the language of the first call
